# Call #define multiple times based on a specific value

Tags: c, macros

If you call something like this in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define REPS ,a
...
int a = 1;

printf("%d" REPS);
```

It will work, but is it possible to call the `REPS` macro multiple times based on an unknown value, like for example, that I want to have five inputs in a `scanf`, yet I want my code to automate it (for example, if `#define REPS ,a[i]` then: `... ,a[1] ,a[2]`)?

Comment: REPS is evaluated at compile time, so it cannot depend on run-time values.  There are hacks but in general you cannot do compile loops with macros.  Instead write a function that takes a count and an array, or an array terminated with a sentinal (like NULL).

Comment: I think it's better to not want to automate stuff like this. Especially as an unexperienced programmer, you're trying to solve the wrong problems. I'm pretty sure this is just an XY-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It will work, but is it possible to call the REPS multiple times based in an unknown value

**No.** `#define` creates a preprocessor macro that you can use in your code, but when the compiler compiles your code, the actual value is substituted for the macro. If you have:

```
#define FOO 7
```

for example, then every occurrence of `FOO` in your code is replaced by `7` before the code is compiled; by the time the compiler sees your code, there's no `#define` and no `FOO`, only `7` wherever `FOO` was. Although there are some other preprocessor commands (e.g. `#if`) that can control whether a given `#define` is evaluated at all, there are no other preprocessor control structures (loops etc.).

> I want to have five inputs in a scanf, yet I want my code to automate it (for example, if #define REPS ,a[i] then: ... ,a[1] ,a[2])?

You can certainly automate something like that; it's just that the preprocessor isn't the right tool for the job. Consider:

```
int reps = 5
//...
for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
    scanf(" %d", &a[i]);
}
```

Comment: I think this will be the best explanation. Your suggested code is actually my first option, is just that it is impossible to lay out in such that the terminal would look theoretically like this: 1, 2, 3  (which also only work for fixed array length)

Comment: @LuigiChan Glad I could help. Your end goal isn't impossible; again, the preprocessor just isn't the right tool for the job. See Allan Wind's answer for a great example of printing your entire array on a single line using a loop.

Answer (score 0):

REPS is evaluated at compile time, so it cannot depend on run-time values in this case `a`. There are hacks but in general you cannot do compile loops with macros.

I suggest you write a function along these lines instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_int_array(size_t n, int a[n]) {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                printf("%d%s", a[i], i + 1 < n ? ", " : "\n");
}

int main() {
        print_int_array(0, (int []) {});
        print_int_array(1, (int []) {1});
        print_int_array(2, (int []) {1, 2});
}
```